# HTML formatting in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to add a formatted column in a Pandas DataFrame when working with it in IPython notebooks? I would like to add a data URL `<img>` and have it display in the cell.

Comment: And you want the image to display in the cell?

Comment: Correct............

Comment: Do we really need this many "...." :)?

Comment: No, but I don't want to fight with the minimum-character-width auto-enforcer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `src` urls are too long, pandas will truncate them when it displays it.  You need to increase the max column width to accomodate that.

track the current max column width

```
current_max_colwidth = pd.get_option('display.max_colwidth')
print(current_max_colwidth)

50
```

Set the option to something big

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)
```

import `HTML` display function

```
from IPython.display import HTML
```

use the dataframe `to_html` with the parameter `escape=False`

```
HTML(
    pd.DataFrame([
            """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2336654.png?theme=default">""",
            """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2543372.png?theme=default">""",
            """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/44330.png?theme=default">"""
        ]).to_html(escape=False))
```

[image]

Set option back

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', current_max_colwidth)
```

---

Wrap it up in a tidy function

```
def my_to_html(df):
    current_max_colwidth = pd.get_option('display.max_colwidth')
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)
    from IPython.display import HTML
    my_html = HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', current_max_colwidth)
    return my_html

df = pd.DataFrame([
        """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2336654.png?theme=default">""",
        """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2543372.png?theme=default">""",
        """<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/44330.png?theme=default">"""
    ])

my_to_html(df)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without having to call `HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))`? can the dataframe do it itself?

Comment: I couldn't find an option for it.  I found one to not escape `latex`... that does us no good.  You could overwrite the `to_html` method for that dataframe, but that is pretty hacky.  I updated post with a function that will do it.

Comment: thanks! it's really hard to find all this information if you're not that familiar w/ libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
# this file is in the same folder as the notebook I'm using on my drive
df['image'] = 'so-logo.png'
df['new'] = df['image'].apply(lambda x: '<img src="{}"/>'.format(x) if x else '')
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

[image: Simple result]

---

Alternatively you can use `df.style`instead of `IPython.display.HTML`. This also allows you to add other formatting, for example to highlight the row on hover:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df['image'] = 'so-logo.png'
df['new'] = df['image'].apply(lambda x: '<img src="{}"/>'.format(x) if x else '')


def hover(hover_color="#ffff99"):
    return dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])

styles = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector="th", props=[("font-size", "150%"),
                               ("text-align", "center")]),
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")])
]
html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
          .set_caption("Hover to highlight."))

html
```

I have my cursor on the second row here:

[image: With hover]